# Camera2 capture() function ignores my SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm trying to capture an image using the Camera2 api, with a specific exposure time.
everything looks fine when it's set to small values like 1/8000 of a second or 1/10.
The problem comes when I try to set it to values like 5 seconds or 30, it seems like the camera limits the exposure time to about 1 second... even if  the SENSOR_INFO_EXPOSURE_TIME_RANGE is:

```
from 13181 to 48369980540(48 seconds).
```

When I get the exposure time from the CaptureResult I get the value I put in, instead of the real exposure time.

I know that my camera can take pictures with higher exposure since my stock camera limit is 30 seconds.

That's the code I tried:

```
final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder =
                mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, 100);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, 10000000000L);//10 seconds




        // Orientation
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation(rotation));

        CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback
                = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                           @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                           @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                showToast("Saved: " + mFile);
                Log.d(TAG, mFile.toString());
                Long expo = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME);
                unlockFocus();
            }
        };

        mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
        mCaptureSession.abortCaptures();
        mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null);
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32896927/1407427

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Camera2 API - How to set long exposure times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855925/camera2-api-how-to-set-long-exposure-times)